# Exercise I2.5 13 from Apostol

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Just came up with a funny proof of this identity from Apostol calculus 1:

Exercise: prove that $A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$

So I did it by contrapositive: suppose that there is some elements $x$ and $y$. Then,

$\big(x \not\in \emptyset \Rightarrow x \not\in A \cap \emptyset\big) \Leftrightarrow \big(y \in A \cap \emptyset \Rightarrow y \in \emptyset\big)$

This is equal to the proof that $A \cap \emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$. Then we prove that $\emptyset \subseteq A \cap \emptyset$, and conclude the equality proof.

But I have a feeling there is something wrong with this proof (or first part of it), since it somehow acknowledges that there **might** be an element in the empty set. Any ideas if it is valid/invalid and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's okay, although your notation is very hard to read with no words. Personally I find reasoning about vacuous things kind of fun, so here's a more direct proof to give you a different flavor:

Since any element $x$ in $A\cap\varnothing$ must be in $\varnothing$, we see that $A\cap\varnothing \subset\varnothing$. But on the other hand, the empty set is a subset of any set, so $\varnothing \subset A\cap\varnothing$, so the sets must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Let's admit that

(1) the complement of the empty set is U ( the universal set)

(2) De Morgan's Law :  Complement of  ( X n Y) = Complement of X  u   Complement of Y ( and reciprocally)

(3) The union of any set X and of the universal set U is equal to the universal set , in symbols : 
X u U = U

(4) if two sets are equal, their complements are equal, and reciprocally

By (4) the proposition to be proved  : A n ∅ = ∅   , is equivalent to :

complement of ( A n ∅) = Complement of ∅

Which is equivalent ( using  (1) and (2)) to :

Complement-of-A  u  U = U

And this last proposition is an instance of the law (3).

Being equivalent to a law of the algebra of sets ( namely to law (3)) , the initial proposition is necessarily true.